# ZXing library An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0 and other issues

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing

I have some troubles with ZXing library and I'm sure that is only a my fault.

First of all, if I launch my app, the app works properly, so I'm sure that I

have all permissions and issues are only during events onStop, onPause...

I follow some example (as is possible to find in this forum) but the following code generates some error

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("Pause", "pause");
    mScannerView.stopCameraPreview();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("Stop", "stop");
    mScannerView.stopCameraPreview();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}
```

But every time I received the error:

```
E/ZXingScannerView: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
at android.hardware.Camera.setHasPreviewCallback(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(Camera.java:878)
at me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView.onPreviewFrame(ZXingScannerView.java:153)
    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1187)                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I already tried to remove the calling

```
        mScannerView.stopCameraPreview();
```

or

```
mScannerView.stopCamera();
```

and without *mScannerView.stopCameraPreview();* the app works, but I'm not sure that the camera is really close and I'm not wasting my battery

Other trouble happens when I rotate the screen or press the back button, and when the application returns active, and I press again my button in order to open again the camera I received the message:

```
W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
```

Have you some suggestion for me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

a partial solution to my troubles. I add into my code this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("Destroy", "destroy");
    mScannerView.stopCameraPreview();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}
```

And now when I press the back button I have no errors into the Logcat, but I have still the error about *Method called after release()* when I rotate the phone. The curious fact is that this error not always happens, but I don't understand which is the cause.